# Are API calls in a mapper considered a bad practice?

Tags: java, oop

It's quite common to use DTOs as API models. Often you need to map those DTOs to other models afterwards. I will keep it really simple with following example:

```java
class RequestDto {
  private String companyId;
  // more fields ..
  // getter, setter etc..
}

class SomeModel {
  private Company company;
  // more fields ..
  // getter, setter etc..
}
```

So in the above case `RequestDto` is the model that is used in the API and `SomeModel` is the model that is used internally by the server for the business logic. Usually you would create a class to map from one to another object, e.g:

```java
class RequestMapper {
  public SomeModel mapRequestToSomeModel(RequestDto request){
    Company company = fetchCompanyFromApi(request.getCompanyId()); // makes a request to another service
    
    SomeModel someModel = new SomeModel();
    someModel.setCompany(company);
    // map more fields..

    return someModel;
  }
}
```

**Question**

Is it a good practice to put external API call logic (like `fetchCompanyFromApi`) inside such mapper functions?
Are there better alternatives? (I like to keep mappers very very simple, but maybe that's just me)

Comment: This is a style question, and bound to be opinionated, so I’m thinking of closing… But I’ll answer anyway.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel is there a way to ask opinionated questions here?

Comment: I don’t think so: “This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.” is one of our reasons for closing. But you see, you got two ansers and no close-vote yet. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a little smelly to me. My (personal) expecption for a mapper, particularly if other mappers are trivial, is to be very very cheap. No database or API calls involved. I would prefer so create some kind of conversion service, which performs the same steps, but is called differently.

A similar question often arises for functions that are called `get…` where I would never expect expensive operations.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, in this case you break single-responsibility principle: you map some data **and** fetch smth from another resource. And in this case you should name your method fetchDataAndMapRequestToModel. Because names should be clear to understand.

I also expect mapper class to do some simple stuff like pure get/set or based on some primitive logic (if A is null set B).